# Java: Newline in strings.xml does not work

Tags: java, android, xml, string, newline

i am trying to print a new line in a text view. i am using a string `<string name="newl">\n</string>` in my strings.xml file.

i want to use the new line in a `output.setText(new StringBuilder().append(output.getText()).append(R.string.newl2).append(input.getText()));`
but instead of a new line it says "2131099673"

I am using android studio and i am debugging on a xperia z2

Comment: *sorry, of course the string in the append method is named right. (R.string.newl)

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. unfortunately, this does not work as well. still displaying the same numbers

Comment: `R.string.newl2` is not a string. It is the identifier of a string resource. Use `getString(R.string.newl2)` to get the string.

Comment: thank you. worked like a charm

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
output.setText(new StringBuilder().append(output.getText()).append(output.getResources().getString(R.string.newl2)).append(input.getText()));
```